# Search data for JTable using PLSQL stored procedure

Tags: java, swing, jdbc, plsql, jtable

I have a `JFrame` in which I have populated some data by stored procedure.  Now I want to search the data through a `JTextField`. I used a `RowSorter` filter method but it didn't filter row in a proper index.

In simple queries, I have used this method to search the data:

```
Statement st = conn.createStatement();
String query = "SELECT t.mach_name , T.Mach_Id FROM KNT_COMMERCIAL_MACH T " + 
    "WHERE T.Mach_Id LIKE '%" + jTextField7.getText() + "%' " + 
    "or t.mach_name like '%" + jTextField7.getText() + "%'";
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);
jTableMachine1.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
```

Can we search data in procedures by the above method? If yes then kindly inform me. Or are there other possibilities to perform searching?

Comment: *"I used a `RowSorter` filter method but it didn't filter row in a proper index."* Sorting and filtering is available for Swing `JTable` components, but a DB has the ability to sort and filter data built into its core. Better to do both sorting and filtering in the DB.

Comment: Also, look into using a [prepared statement](https://www.google.com/search?q=prepared+statement+java+jdbc) when accessing the DB.